# Reading in a price (eg. $89.95) into a double

Tags: c++

I am working on an assignment that requires that I read in data from a txt file.
The data fields are for books, so I have a title, book id, price,  quantity. 
Everything is working well except for reading in the price. I am using atof() for that which works when I remove the '$' sign from the front of the price, but returns '0' when the '$' is there.

How do I make it ignore the '$' ?

An example of the txt file:

```
Introduction to programming languages
1
$89.99
100
```

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>       


using namespace std;

int main() {
    char title[50];
    char strBookid[10];
    char strPrice[10];
    char strAmount[10];
    int bookId;
    double price;
    int amount;
    ifstream filein("bookfile.txt");

    filein.getline(title, 50);
    cout << "Title : " << title << endl;
    filein.getline(strBookid, 10);
    cout << "BookId as a string : " << strBookid << endl;
    filein.getline(strPrice, 10);
    cout << "Price as a string : " << strPrice << endl;
    filein.getline(strAmount, 10);
    cout << "Qty as a string: " << strAmount << endl;

    bookId = std::atoi(strBookid);
    cout << "The Book ID as an int : " << bookId << endl;
    price = std::atof(strPrice);
    cout << "The price as a double : " << price << endl;


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `price = std::atof(strPrice + 1);` probably conditionally.

Comment: Not all problems have elegant solutions. Just look to see if `$` is there and, if so, go past it. More comprehensive: ignore all non-numeric characters at the beginning of the string. Just send the number component of the string to `atof()`.

Comment: don't do it, store it in unit of integer cents.

Comment: POSIX provides [`strfmon()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strfmon.html) which is used to format money.  That formatting shows you some of the complexities that the hypothetical (non-existent) `strpmon()` function would need to deal with in full.  You could look at [What are the formal and practical constraints on the values in `struct lconv` describing a locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261684/what-are-the-formal-and-practical-constraints-on-the-values-in-struct-lconv-de) if you don't mind having your mind boggled.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You see, the folks behind the C++ standard love money and they know we all do, so they put up a nice way to read money in a generic manner in C++ The [`std::get_money`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/money_get)

You can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>   
#include <locale>    //add this    


using namespace std;

int main() {
    char title[50];
    char strBookid[10];
    char strPrice[10];
    char strAmount[10];
    int bookId;
    long double price;   //changed! get_money only supports long double
    int amount;
    ifstream filein("bookfile.txt");

    filein.getline(title, 50);
    cout << "Title : " << title << endl;
    filein.getline(strBookid, 10);
    cout << "BookId as a string : " << strBookid << endl;

    filein.imbue(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));      /// added
    filein >> std::get_money(price);               ///changed
    price /= 100;         //get_money uses the lowest denomination, in this case cents, so we convert it $ by dividing the value by 100
    cout << "Price as a string : $" << price << endl;    ///changed

    filein.getline(strAmount, 10);
    cout << "Qty as a string: " << strAmount << endl;

    bookId = std::atoi(strBookid);
    cout << "The Book ID as an int : " << bookId << endl;
    price = std::atof(strPrice);
    cout << "The price as a double : " << price << endl;


  return 0;
}
```

---

As a second alternative, you can modify your original code to test for the `$` sign manually... (see the snippet below

```
    ......many lines skipped ...........

    bookId = std::atoi(strBookid);
    cout << "The Book ID as an int : " << bookId << endl;
    price = std::atof(strPrice[0] == '$' ? strPrice+1 : strPrice );   //modified
    cout << "The price as a double : " << price << endl;


  return 0;
}
```